# Cross-Domain Authentication and Session Sharing Between Multiple Parent Websites and a Common Child App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, web, cross-domain

I have a website with a URL of **([www.parent1.com](http://www.parent1.com))**, and inside this **parent1** website there is an iframe. In the iframe, I'm loading a **React app** with a URL of **([www.child.com](http://www.child.com))** and **login to the child app inside the iframe** of the **(parent1.com)** website. There is another parent website with a URL of **([www.parent2.com](http://www.parent2.com))**, and this site also has an iframe inside it that loads the **same child app** with the URL of **(child.com)**. What I want is that if I login to the child app of **(parent1.com)** and if I open **(parent2.com)** in another tab, the child app of **(parent2.com)** should be **logged in**. Please give me your ideas on how to achieve this.

The problem I'm facing is that even though I login to the child app **(child.com)** in the iframe of the **(parent1.com)** website, And then, if I open the **(parent2.com)** website in another tab, the child app **(child.com)** in the iframe of **(parent2.com)** is **not logged in**.

In each **parent website** there is a **phone number field**. On phone input change I'm calling to an API and finds if there is a valid user for the given number. if the user is valid, I'm sending an OTP to that number and if the user enters the correct OTP, I'm getting an **access token** which can be used to login to the react app (child app). Then from the parent website I'm sending the token to the react app through **postMessage**. In the react app it listens to message event and if the token is available the react app will be logged-in.

Comment: How do you save the session information? Do you have access to the react app and can adjust things within it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Geshode the question is updated which will answer your question, thanks.

Comment: Can you not save the token in a cookie and check for it, when opening a parent site. If it is there, send it.

Comment: @Geshode I tried it, but the problem is that when I save cookies in (www.parent1.com) site, they are not accessible in (www.parent2.com) site.

Comment: Could also use localStorage.

Comment: @Geshode tried both ways still not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the code, which you tried it with? Also tell us exactly what part doesn't work.